# Mixed Poisson distribution with exponential distributed $\lambda$ in EM

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, poisson-distribution

I am reading a paper for Expectation Maximization algorithm which can be found
[here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/F94ABDC70F083625488EB87B446FE160/S0515036100014033a.pdf/em-algorithm-for-mixed-poisson-and-other-discrete-distributions.pdf).Is from a greek professor of statistics with the title of the paper "EM ALGORITHM FOR MIXED POISSON AND OTHER DISCRETE DISTRIBUTIONS"

I have a problem in page 7 that says : " Suppose that $$g(\theta | \lambda) =  \lambda \exp (– \theta  \lambda), \theta,  \lambda > 0,$$ i.e. $\theta_{i}$ follows an exponential distribution with mean $ \lambda^{-1}$, then the resulting geometric distribution has probability function given by:

$$P(x| \lambda) = (\frac{ \lambda}{1+ \lambda})(\frac{1}{ 1+\lambda})^{x}$$

$x = 0,1,\dots,\lambda>0$
My questions are:

**1)** How he ended in the geometric distribution?

**2)** How someone can use the $$P(x|\phi) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(-\theta)\theta^{x}}{x!} d G(\theta|\phi)$$ as the probability function of mixed Poisson distribution in the above ? Or it is irrelevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper initially assumes that $X|\theta \sim \text{Poisson}(\theta)$. Then, under the case (in 4.1) that $\theta|\lambda \sim \text{expo}(\lambda)$, we can compute:

\begin{align*}
p(x|\lambda) 
&= \int_0^\infty p(x,\theta|\lambda) d\theta\\
&= \int_0^\infty p(x|\theta)p(\theta|\lambda) d\theta\\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\theta}\theta^x}{x!} \lambda e^{-\theta \lambda} d\theta\\
&=\frac{\lambda}{x!} \int_0^\infty \theta^x e^{-\theta (\lambda+1)} d\theta\\
\end{align*}
The easiest way to solve this integral is to note that the integrand can be rewritten so that it is the pdf of a Gamma random variable with shape parameter $x+1$ and rate parameter $\lambda + 1$. So

\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \theta^x e^{-\theta (\lambda+1)} d\theta
&=\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{(\lambda + 1)^{(x+1)}} \int_0^\infty \frac{(\lambda + 1)^{(x+1)}}{\Gamma(x+1)}\theta^x e^{-\theta (\lambda+1)} d\theta\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{(\lambda + 1)^{(x+1)}} \int_0^\infty \text{Gamma}(\theta; x+1, \lambda+1) d\theta\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{(\lambda + 1)^{(x+1)}}
\end{align*}

Putting this back in to the previous working we get:
\begin{align*}
p(x|\lambda) 
=\frac{\lambda}{x!} \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{(\lambda + 1)^{(x+1)}}
=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+1} \frac{1}{(\lambda + 1)^{x}}
\end{align*}

Comment: In your first section of your answer you compute the unconditional likelihood right?

Comment: So the last integral equals to 1?

Comment: @HungryHomer What do you mean by unconditional likelihood, wouldn't that be $p(x)$, whereas I compute $p(x|\lambda)$

Comment: @TheRed Yes, since a density is being integrated with respect to its argument, it must integrate to 1

Comment: @WeakLearner equation 1 from the paper.I think that is that you did.Not the conditional p.f